# Hidden properties in Tailwind for Mobile/Tablet/Desktop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am new to web dev, studying and practicing it.
I mainly use Tailwind (next.js, react).

When building my app, I used the Mobile First Approach... although the className becomes very long in some cases, mainly because I have to specify margins, padding, and layout for every breakpoint (sm, md, lg mainly).

So, in complicated views, I tend to build the components separately in order to have:

```
{/* Mobile view  */} :
<div className='md-8 md:hidden bg-picture bg-cover'> some content (like pictures or other things) </div>

{/* Tablet/Desktop view  */} :
<div className='hidden md-4 bg-picture bg-cover'> It has the same content but, of course, is made for the device I am on. </div>
```

In this case, I technically have a Container that is hidden and one that is not, but I am not sure if it also hurts performance; the website may have a copy of the same HTML Tags, such as a hidden H1, but should not consider it (because is hidden) is this correct?.

I want to start to build good habits.
Thanks

---

I am not sure how it the page is managed, -> I use Next.js 13+
My idea was that if the content is hidden, it will not be rendered, but html will anyway exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are worried about performance, you need to know that elements with `display: none;` may be hidden from the user's eyes but their components will still exist and get rendered any time they have to. so, to optimize the performance, you need to take the useless components out of the react tree by using JS and returning `null`. I will give you an example of a component that will render its children only when the viewport size is what we need.

```
const viewports = {
    "sm": 640,
    "md": 768,
    "lg": 1024,
    "xl": 1280,
    "2xl": 1536,
}

const MediaQuery = ({ ssr = false, min, max, children }) => {
    const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(ssr)

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = () => {
            const shouldShow = window.innerWidth >= (viewports[min] || 0) && window.innerWidth <= (viewports[max] || Infinity)

             setShouldShow(shouldShow)
        }

        listener()

        window.addEventListener("resize", listener)
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", listener)
        
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", listener)
            window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", listener)
        }
    }, [])

    if(!shouldShow) return null

    return children
}
```

now in this example, I will show you how to use it and what each prop does:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <MediaQuery max="md" ssr>
                <Content/>
            </MediaQuery>

            <MediaQuery min="md">
                <Content/>
            </MediaQuery>
        </>
    )
}
```

the `min` and `max` props handle the `children` visibility based on the viewport width. we can also use both `max` and `min` props at the same time, to show the children only between a specific viewport range.

and what does the `ssr` prop do? As we do not access the `window` object in the server, we cannot calculate the viewport size. therefore, we cannot check whether we should show the children or not. however, we need to render one of the components on the initial render to help the SEO. so I added a prop called `ssr` that will be the default value of the `shouldShow` state which makes the component, render the children on the initial render if it is enabled. we can use it for one of the components to show it by default to help the SEO (mostly the one that has more useful data for search engines)

feel free to ask if you have questions, or if you need something more.